# kähler differentials of power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field (for example a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) and let $A = \mathcal{O}_K[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ which we consider as a topological ring.

I would have thought that the kähler differentials of $A$ would be $A\,dX_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A\,dX_n$ be it seems (for example see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01396625?LI=true) 3.7 page 392) that this corresponds to the "continuous" differentials i.e. the module representing the functor send a $A$ module $M$ to the continuous derivations from $A$ to $M$

Why is it so and what is the usal ring of Kähler differentials of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

The (abstract) Kähler differentials $\Omega^1_{A/O_K}$ as $A$-module is not finitely generated, cf.Exercise 6.1.2 of Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetric curves by Qing Liu. If $n=1$, $f\in O_K[[X]]$, we can define $f'\in O_K[[X]]$ by formal differential, but $df$ may differ from $f'(X)dX$ in $\Omega_{A/O_K}^1$ (as we cannot apply $d(g+h)=dg+dh$ infinitely many times!). However, if we use the completion $\hat{\Omega}^1_{A/O_K}$ defined in EGA IV1 (20.4.3) , then it would be $\oplus_{i=1}^nAdx_i$. I guess it is the continuous" differential" used by Fontaine.